# Dropdown list default value on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, binding, dropdownlistfor

I'm working on an asp project. I have a situation where I need to search files and display in gridview. The gridview have three drop down list, my problem now is how can I show the default value of my dropdown based on the result set returned when I click the search button, since I already set the default value of the drop down ("Please Select") on data row bound. Because at first load my drop down should show "please select" value. Thanks a lot for the help. below is my code.

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int uFlag = 0;
    string uploadFlag = this.ddlUploadDate.SelectedValue;
    string fileName = this.txtSearchText.Text;
    string uploadDt = this.txtDate.Text;
    string status = this.ddlStatus.SelectedValue.ToString();

    List<EventFile> fileSearch = new List<EventFile>();
    fileSearch = CoMailAssociationDAL.SearchFile(uFlag, fileName, uploadDt, status);

    gvwAssociation.DataSource = fileSearch;
    gvwAssociation.DataBind();
}

 protected void gvwAssociation_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    ListItem Item = new ListItem();
    Item.Text = "Please Select";
    Item.Value = "0";
    Item.Selected = true;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ddlpool = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlpool");
        DropDownList ddlyear = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlyear");
        DropDownList ddlevent = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlevent");

        ddlpool.DataSource = CoMailAssociationDAL.GetCoBindEvents();
        ddlpool.DataBind();
        ddlpool.Items.Insert(0, Item);

        ddlevent.DataSource = CoMailAssociationDAL.GetCoBindEvents();
        ddlevent.DataBind();
        ddlevent.Items.Insert(0, Item);

        for (int intCount = 2013; intCount <= 2020; intCount++)
        {
            ddlyear.Items.Add(intCount.ToString());   
            ddlyear.SelectedIndex = 1;             
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a condition in your grid RowDataBound event by taking one hiddenfield in itemtemplate for value from database and find that as

```
for (int intCount = 2013; intCount <= 2020; intCount++)
    {
        ddlyear.Items.Add(intCount.ToString());   
        HiddenField result= GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("hdnpool") as HiddenField;
        if(result!=null)
         ddlyear.SelectedIndex =result.value;
        else
         ddlyear.SelectedIndex = 1;             
    }
```

In grid please use below for each dropdown:

```
  <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddpool" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnpool" Value="<%# Eval("PoolColumninDB") %>" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'm quite confused, I need to set the default value of the three drop down lists( ddlpool,ddlevent,ddlyear) based on the list returned by the method SearchFile at the Search button event. How can I achieve this? Since my dropdown has default value on data row bound.

Comment: You should use three hiddenfields with you dropdowns in gridview as

Comment: Hi I apologize if its too much to ask, but can you show me an example? I'm a newbie in asp development. Thanks much for the help.

Comment: I am updating my answer for you now. Please see.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I'm trying it now.

Comment: you can find the value to be set for dropdown as hiddenfield value. Hope It will help you. Please refer complete above again.

Comment: Also if you are stiil unable to find Please let me know your source for aspx and its cs file. GoodLuck

Answer (score -2):

Have you try this

```
for (int intCount = 2013; intCount <= 2020; intCount++)
    {
        ddlyear.Items.Add(intCount.ToString());   
        ddlyear.SelectedValue= 1;             
    }
```